# Error "Input string was not in a correct format." Gauss method

Tags: c#, sharpdevelop

I got some trouble with the code and running it.

My code:

```
        //
        // TODO: Add constructor code after the InitializeComponent() call.
        //
    textBox1.Text=("0.42");
    textBox2.Text=("1.14");
    textBox3.Text=("-0.71");
    textBox4.Text=("-1.13");
    textBox5.Text=("-2.15");
    textBox6.Text=("0.81");
    textBox7.Text=("7.05");
    textBox8.Text=("5.11");
    textBox9.Text=("-0.02");
    textBox10.Text=("6.15");
    textBox11.Text=("-4.16");
    textBox12.Text=("-0.17");
    }

    void Button1Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        double z1,z2,z3,x1,x2,x3,c1,c2,c3,a1,a2,a3,n,s1,s2,s3;          
        z1=Convert.ToDouble(textBox1.Text);
        z2=Convert.ToDouble(textBox2.Text);
        z3=Convert.ToDouble(textBox3.Text);
        x1=Convert.ToDouble(textBox4.Text);
        x2=Convert.ToDouble(textBox5.Text);
        x3=Convert.ToDouble(textBox6.Text);
        c1=Convert.ToDouble(textBox7.Text);
        c2=Convert.ToDouble(textBox8.Text);
        c3=Convert.ToDouble(textBox9.Text);
        a1=Convert.ToDouble(textBox10.Text);
        a2=Convert.ToDouble(textBox11.Text);
        a3=Convert.ToDouble(textBox12.Text);            
        n=x1/z1;            
        textBox24.Text=Convert.ToString(z1=n*z1);
        textBox23.Text=Convert.ToString(z2=n*z2);
        textBox22.Text=Convert.ToString(z3=n*z3);
        textBox19.Text=Convert.ToString(x1=x1-z1);
        textBox20.Text=Convert.ToString(x2=x2-z2);
        textBox21.Text=Convert.ToString(x3=x3-z3);
        textBox13.Text=Convert.ToString(a1=a1*n);
        textBox14.Text=Convert.ToString(a2=a2-a1);          
        n=c1/z1;            
        textBox24.Text=Convert.ToString(z1=n*z1);
        textBox23.Text=Convert.ToString(z2=n*z2);
        textBox22.Text=Convert.ToString(z3=n*z3);
        textBox16.Text=Convert.ToString(c1=c1-z1);
        textBox17.Text=Convert.ToString(c2=c2-z2);
        textBox18.Text=Convert.ToString(c3=c3-z3);
        textBox13.Text=Convert.ToString(a1=a1*n);
        textBox15.Text=Convert.ToString(a3=a3-a1);          
        n=c2/x2;
        textBox32.Text=Convert.ToString(x2=x2*n);
        textBox33.Text=Convert.ToString(x3=x3*n);
        textBox29.Text=Convert.ToString(c2=c2-x2);
        textBox30.Text=Convert.ToString(c3=c3-x3);
        textBox26.Text=Convert.ToString(a2=a2*n);
        textBox27.Text=Convert.ToString(a3=a3-a2);
        textBox36.Text=textBox24.Text;
        textBox35.Text=textBox23.Text;
        textBox34.Text=textBox22.Text;
        textBox25.Text=textBox13.Text;
        n=(1/c3);
        s1=Math.Round(n*a3,4);
        label28.Text=("c="+s1);
        s2=Math.Round((1/x2)*(a2-(x3*s1)),4);
        label29.Text=("b="+s2);
        s3=Math.Round((1/z1)*(a1-(z2*s2)-(z3*s1)),4);
        label30.Text=("a="+s3);     
    }
}
```

This program is Gauss method exercise.

When I run the program I try to push the button but then the error pops out:

> ```
> System.FormatException: Input string was not in a correct format.
>    at System.Number.ParseDouble(String value, NumberStyles options, NumberFormatInfo numfmt)
>    at System.Convert.ToDouble(String value)
>    at gausa_metode_2_variants.MainForm.Button1Click(Object sender, EventArgs e) in c:\Users\NIKS\Documents\SharpDevelop Projects\gausa metode 2 variants\gausa metode 2 variants\MainForm.cs:line 48
>    at System.Windows.Forms.Control.OnClick(EventArgs e)
>    at System.Windows.Forms.Button.OnClick(EventArgs e)
>    at System.Windows.Forms.Button.OnMouseUp(MouseEventArgs mevent)
>    at System.Windows.Forms.Control.WmMouseUp(Message& m, MouseButtons button, Int32 clicks)
>    at System.Windows.Forms.Control.WndProc(Message& m)
>    at System.Windows.Forms.ButtonBase.WndProc(Message& m)
>    at System.Windows.Forms.Button.WndProc(Message& m)
>    at System.Windows.Forms.Control.ControlNativeWindow.OnMessage(Message& m)
>    at System.Windows.Forms.Control.ControlNativeWindow.WndProc(Message& m)
>    at System.Windows.Forms.NativeWindow.DebuggableCallback(IntPtr hWnd, Int32 msg, IntPtr wparam, IntPtr lparam)
>    at System.Windows.Forms.UnsafeNativeMethods.DispatchMessageW(MSG& msg)
>    at System.Windows.Forms.Application.ComponentManager.System.Windows.Forms.UnsafeNativeMethods.IMsoComponentManager.FPushMessageLoop(IntPtr dwComponentID, Int32 reason, Int32 pvLoopData)
>    at System.Windows.Forms.Application.ThreadContext.RunMessageLoopInner(Int32 reason, ApplicationContext context)
>    at System.Windows.Forms.Application.ThreadContext.RunMessageLoop(Int32 reason, ApplicationContext context)
>    at System.Windows.Forms.Application.Run(Form mainForm)
>    at gausa_metode_2_variants.Program.Main(String[] args) in c:\Users\NIKS\Documents\SharpDevelop Projects\gausa metode 2 variants\gausa metode 2 variants\Program.cs:line 27
> ```

Comment: If my answer helped you, please give me an upvote. Thx.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a problem converting the specified `string` to `double` in line 48.
That will be one of the `**=Convert.ToDouble(textBox*.Text);`.

Depending on the region and regional settings I am pretty sure you need to write `,` for the decimal seperator (at least some countries use `,` instead of `.`).

Answer (score 0):

it can't parse string to double on of theese lines

```
    z1=Convert.ToDouble(textBox1.Text);
    z2=Convert.ToDouble(textBox2.Text);
    z3=Convert.ToDouble(textBox3.Text);
    x1=Convert.ToDouble(textBox4.Text);
    x2=Convert.ToDouble(textBox5.Text);
    x3=Convert.ToDouble(textBox6.Text);
    c1=Convert.ToDouble(textBox7.Text);
    c2=Convert.ToDouble(textBox8.Text);
    c3=Convert.ToDouble(textBox9.Text);
    a1=Convert.ToDouble(textBox10.Text);
    a2=Convert.ToDouble(textBox11.Text);
    a3=Convert.ToDouble(textBox12.Text);
```

when i check the textbox values seems fine. Nothing wrong, maybe you are changing the value of textbox in runtime.
At the end the error message says:

```
System.FormatException: Input string was not in a correct format.
   at System.Number.ParseDouble(String value, NumberStyles options, NumberFormatInfo numfmt)
   at System.Convert.ToDouble(String value) at line 48
```

so just check your value you are trying to parse on line 48